# Word for song sung at a burial?

Tags: single-word-requests

What would a song sung at a burial be called ? (One word)

For example: *A melancholic  ____ was sung by the mourners at the burial of the youngest son of the mayor.*

Comment: There is no single-word term, to my knowledge, that will do for the whole set. 'Funeral song' has no strict synonyms in English: some are inspirational, even joyful, rather than being dirges/laments/coronachs/threnodies.

Comment: I had 4 words spring into my head but all 4 are already in individual answers. Darn it. Anyone who's read McCaffrey's Pern books knows *threnody*!!

Comment: Are you looking for the contemporary word people would use, esp. in speaking, or a jumble of rare, archaic and literary terms that only even occur in print, and even then not so much in the last 200+ years?

Comment: Of all the answers below, requiem and lament are the only ones you should take seriously.

Answer (score 117, accepted):

A [dirge](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/dirge) is such a song.

> a lament for the dead, especially one forming part of a funeral rite.
>
> a mournful song, piece of music, or poem.

-Oxford Living Dictionary

Example:

> A melancholic dirge was sung by the mourners at the burial of the youngest son of the mayor.

Answer (score 69):

**"elegy"** is also appropriate.

> 2. a :  a song or poem expressing sorrow or lamentation especially for one who is dead

**Source:** https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/elegy

Comment: This would have been my go-to answer, but I guess it can also be a poem hence dirge was accepted..

Comment: This is a MUCH nicer sounding word than dirge.

Comment: I don't follow your claims of "nicer sounding."  That seems entirely subjective.  For instance, consider the following statement someone could make:  "Dirge is a MUCH nicer sounding word than elegy."

Comment: @bubbleking This entire conversation is subjective. Dirge has negative overtones the others do not.

Comment: @niico That's a good point. I took your statement as a judgment on the aesthetics of the word's pronunciation, not its overtones.

Answer (score 61):

I think you could use "**requiem**".

According to the [Merriam-Webster online Dictionary](https://www.merriam-webster.com/), the second meaning of "*requiem*" seems to be what you are looking for:

```
Definition of requiem 

1 :  a mass for the dead 
2 
  a :  a solemn chant (such as a dirge) for the repose of the dead 
  b :  something that resembles such a solemn chant 
3 
  a :  a musical setting of the mass for the dead 
  b :  a musical composition in honor of the dead
```

**Source**: https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/requiem

Comment: I always understood requiem to apply more to a group of people rather than an individual, but I can't find anything definitive either way.

Answer (score 29):

Such a song can be called a **[threnody](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/threnody)**. From Merriam-Webster:

> a song of lamentation for the dead :  elegy

Comment: That's a good word. Your answer would benefit from including the definition in the text and maybe a sentence or two of your own explanation.

Comment: This is the best answer in my opinion.  Dirge is an old-fashioned word.  Requiem is specific to a funeral mass.  Elegy is a bit too general.

Comment: @Palizsche _Dirge_ may be old-fashioned, but so is _threnody_; more so, I’d say. It’s also a lot more obscure, and no less general than _elegy_ or _lament_.

Comment: I've added the definition and (very brief) citation from your link; feel free to roll back the edit if you really don't want it, and/or add further explanation of your own.

Comment: **Way too rare and archaic**. Whether it *can be called* that, and *whether the average person would ever call it that* (or even be aware of this rare and archaic word), are two entirely different things.

Comment: I believe I suggested the word first; as 'A melancholic threnody' would be tautologous, I did not consider it a fitting answer.

Answer (score 17):

A lament is a suitable word also - a lament implies sadness, grief, sorrow - a dirge also implies miserable and slow.

Comment: Good answers on this site tend to have research to back them up. For a single word request this would normally include a referenced dictionary definition.

Comment: Lament, as in "Dido's Lament" from Purcell's opera Dido and Aeneas.

Answer (score 5):

If the burial is a Christian religious service then the song might be a "**hymn**" (which is a generic word used for all songs sung at religious services, not only at burials).

None of the words suggested in other answers would do, if it is a Christian religious service ... the other words are English-language but they are uncommon and/or pagan.

- Dirge: nearly tuneless, probably repetitive
- Requiem: probably lasts the whole mass i.e. it's the whole service set to music, and performed by professional musicians
- Threnody: obscure